# SSIS Lookup transformation not capturing non matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, lookup

I'm using the lookup transformation to look back at my data warehouse table to find any deleted records from production and then send them to a staging table to be removed from the datawarehouse table.

Logically, if a record is removed in the production table and exists in the datawarehouse table this lookup should find it and redirect it to `No Match Output` correct?

The issue is the lookup isn't finding the non-matching records or I'm doing something backwards.

I should add that in production there are 4 identical databases for four different regions. My package loops through each one by looping through the connection strings in a config file. Then all of these records are marked with which database they came from and added to the datawarehouse table.

This is the part inside my data flow task that isn't working properly:

[image]

Inside the "Fact Table" OLE DB source I'm pulling the records from my fact table where the `Region` equals whichever region the connection string identifies by using numbers 1 - 4. I put the query in a variable so that it can be dynamic. I'm also only pulling the columns that cannot be null inside the staging table in order to minimize the amount I'm pulling and I only *really* need the ID and Region column to delete the records because they should be unique within their respective regions.

**Inside `FindDeletes` variable:**

```
"SELECT ID ,
        ParentItemID ,
        IsTransPerPiece ,
        PerPieceCostQuantity ,
        PerPieceCost ,
        PerPieceUnitCost ,
        OriginalPerPieceCostQuantity ,
        OriginalTransFee ,
        TransFee ,
        CostTrans ,
        CostLabor ,
        OriginalCostQuantity ,
        OriginalFacilityFees ,
        FacilityFees ,
        Region ,
        HashValue ,
        CreateDate 
FROM dbo.FactInvoiceWasteManifests
WHERE Region = CASE " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] +
       " WHEN 1 THEN 'NE'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'BALT'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'NY' 
        WHEN 4 THEN 'PA'
        END "
```

**Inside OLE DB Source showing the variable query:**

[image]

Next we go into the transformation in which I redirect rows that don't match to the `No Match Output`

[image]

The connection here is to production and the query here is again dynamic because the `Region` column doesn't exist in production.

[image]

**Showing the expression for the lookup SQL query:**

[image]

```
"SELECT  ID,
        CASE " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] +
       " WHEN 1 THEN CAST('NE' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        WHEN 2 THEN CAST('BALT' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        WHEN 3 THEN CAST('NY' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        WHEN 4 THEN CAST('PA' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        END AS Region 
FROM    dbo.InvoiceWasteManifests;"
```

**UPDATED QUERY:**

```
"SELECT  ID,
        CASE 
        WHEN " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] + "=1 THEN CAST('NE' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        WHEN " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] + "=2 THEN CAST('BALT' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        WHEN " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] + "=3 THEN CAST('NY' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        WHEN " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] + "=4 THEN CAST('PA' AS NVARCHAR(25))
        END AS Region 
FROM    dbo.InvoiceWasteManifests;"
```

[image]

Lastly, I join the two tables on `Region` and then search on ID. The result is nothing happens and no records are redirected anywhere.

Comment: why the sql command is `case 1 when 1 then...` ?

Comment: That's just what the expression evaluates to because I have a value of 1 in my connection string ID variable at the moment but that variable changes when I actually run the query.  So it actually looks like this: `SELECT  ID, CASE " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] + " WHEN 1 THEN CAST('NE' AS NVARCHAR(25))` but inside an expression.

Comment: I am little bit confused, the correct syntax is `case when 1 then ..` in your case, but you put one more `1` in this, I guess it should be `'case when'+ (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID]+'then...'` in your dynamic query

Comment: I see what you're saying and thank you for your comment. It was working with the above query but I changed it to how you suggested but got the same results. `"SELECT  ID, CASE WHEN " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] + "=1 THEN CAST('NE' AS NVARCHAR(25)) WHEN " + (DT_WSTR, 2) @[User::ConnectionStringID] + "=2 THEN CAST('BALT' AS NVARCHAR(25))...` I also verified to make sure that the ConnectionStringID is actually changing and it is.

Comment: Could you paste the new dynamic query here? Seems the syntax is still not good, i will look through your project again. btw you are not only using that in one place

Comment: When you say nothing happens, do you mean the oledb source query returns no row or all rows are matched, or something else?

Comment: I think you're right. When I clicked into the expression box it says `Object does not match target type` which I guess means I need to convert it back to an INT before comparing it. I updated my question to show the new dynamic query.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz it shows that no rows are redirected to the `Lookup No Match Ouput` everything up to that lookup transformation seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I didn't fully understand how the Lookup Transformation works. I solved my problem this morning by also using the `ID` column as a join instead of caching it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the first dynamic query you need to put:

```
  --declare @sql varchar(max)
  --declare @ConnectionStringID varchar(50) =1
    set @sql = 
    'SELECT ID ,
            ParentItemID ,
            IsTransPerPiece ,
            PerPieceCostQuantity ,
            PerPieceCost ,
            PerPieceUnitCost ,
            OriginalPerPieceCostQuantity ,
            OriginalTransFee ,
            TransFee ,
            CostTrans ,
            CostLabor ,
            OriginalCostQuantity ,
            OriginalFacilityFees ,
            FacilityFees ,
            Region ,
            HashValue ,
            CreateDate 
    FROM dbo.FactInvoiceWasteManifests
    WHERE Region = CASE 
            WHEN ' +  @ConnectionStringID + '=1 THEN ''''''''+CAST(''NE'' AS NVARCHAR(25))+''''''''
            WHEN ' + @ConnectionStringID + '=2 THEN ''''''''+CAST(''BALT'' AS NVARCHAR(25))+''''''''
            WHEN ' +  @ConnectionStringID + '=3 THEN ''''''''+CAST(''NY'' AS NVARCHAR(25))+''''''''
            WHEN ' + @ConnectionStringID + '=4 THEN ''''''''+CAST(''PA'' AS NVARCHAR(25))+''''''''
            END' 
  --print (@Sql)
```

Comment: Try to print this result to see what is the difference between yours and mine, seems like you missed single quote when doing the `where` condition. Make the same change to the later part, then try to run the package again